# Run Spark with additional parameter through Zeppelin

Tags: parameters, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I wand Zeppelin to start Spark with couple additional parameters (--total-executor-cores 200 --executor-memory 20g --driver-memory 5g) I am trying to add these parameters to spark interpreter through Zeppelin UI. I click edit button and add these three parameters but when I click save they disappear and I can see that my Spark was started by Zeppelin without these parameters.

Can you give me a tip how can I ask Zeppelin to start Spark with additional parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` (or `conf/zeppelin-env.sh.template`).  In the comments in that file under "Spark interpreter configurations" section:

```
# export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS                   # (optional) extra options to pass to spark submit. eg) "--driver-memory 512M --executor-memory 1G".
```